# A dot in a text: width/height in em and border-radius

Tags: css, border-radius

I want to do one very simple thing.
A dot within a text. I want to specify the size of the dot in em.

```
height: 0.35em;
width: 0.35em;
border-radius: 50%;
```

My problem is that the dot does not look round.

[image]

If I define the size in px it works.

```
height: 6px;
width: 6px;
border-radius: 50%;
```

[image]

I think the problem is the small size. Is there a trick for this?

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4rtpfu18/

**Edit:**
I fixed this by using svg, that seems to work properly in different font-sizes. It feels like a detour to use svg for such a simple thing.

```
height: 0.375em;
width: 0.375em;
display: inline-block;
bottom: 0.11em;
position: relative;
margin-left: 0.1em;
margin-right: 0.1em;
background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg viewBox=%220 0 10 10%22 xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E%3Ccircle cx=%225%22 cy=%225%22 r=%225%22 /%3E%3C/svg%3E');
```

Comment: https://icon-sets.iconify.design/mdi/circle/

Answer (score 1):

If you use the equivalent number `px` in `em` it's working properly.

I found it in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp).

```css
p{
  font-size: 100%;
}


.circle{    
    height: 0.375em;
    width: 0.375em;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0.23em;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    }
    
    .circle-px{    
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0.23em;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    }
```

```html
<p>
Lorem Ipsum <span class="circle"></span> Lorem Ipsum
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum <span class="circle-px"></span> Lorem Ipsum
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I wanted to use the dot in different fontsizes. In some sizes its looking great but not in every one.

Comment: You're welcome! Every size do you want in `px`, you can be converted into `em`.